# If a*b*c=8 then what is minimum value of (2+a)(2+b)(2+c)

Tags: inequality, optimization

If $abc=8$ and $a,b,c >0$, then what is minimum possible value of $(2+a)(2+b)(2+c)$?

**Edit**: I got the answer and have posted it below.

Comment: What have you tried? AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I didn't tried that actually it didn't click me.

Comment: I got answer,thanks

Comment: If you have the answer, please write it down below and accept it.

Comment: You must have some bounds otherwise a=b=c=2 is good because the expression is always increasing positive.

Answer (score 3):

I saw comment of A.M., G.M. inequality and solved it on my own. just posting answer[image]

Comment: Can you render it into text?  Thanks.

Comment: How could this lead to values for a,b and c?

Comment: You still have to show in your thesis that number $64$ is the minimum, i.e there exist $a,b,c$ such that....

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this directly using the method of Lagrange multipliers: the critical points are solutions to
\begin{align*}
(2+a)(2+b) + \lambda a b &=0\\
(2+a)(2+c) + \lambda a c &=0\\
(2+b)(2+c) + \lambda b c &=0\\
abc &= 8,
\end{align*}
and eliminating equations gives you $a=b=c=2$.

You don't need to consider the case where any of your inequality constraints are active, since your objective function diverges as, say, $a\to0$.